# African palm oil locusts seasoning & preparation?

Tags: oil, seasoning, entomophagy

In Africa, frying locusts in palm oil is common. What kind of stores might sell them? What's the basic technique for frying them, and how would I add seasoning?

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't entertain recipe requests here. The internet is a wealth of information, though, even for stuff like this. You should be able to find a recipe.

Comment: Are you asking about things like how to season them or just about the basic technique for frying them? The former is a recipe request as mentioned, the latter seems good though!

Comment: @Jefromi the latter

Comment: Where are you @Geremia? Availability will be very different depending on your location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good information at [InsectsAreFood](http://www.insectsarefood.com/faq.html). Scroll down for a decent list of places to buy. There is also a site called BizarreFood.com that has a [shopping page](http://www.bizarrefood.com/edible-insects-bugs) with all sorts of bagged and canned bugs. It appears that the UK has the best-developed edible insect markets. If you live elsewhere, you might want to research your country's laws, regulations and requirements before you order.